# How to update TextBox using wpf, IronPython

Tags: wpf, xaml, textbox, ironpython

I have an aplication in IronPython where I load my xaml with wpf: "wpf.LoadComponent(....xaml)"

I have a Button and a TextBox in my app and when I push the button, the app start doing a 2 minute work, I need to update the textbox of the aplication during this work.
But I can´t do it. My textBox only update it when the 2 minute work finish.

Any help?
Thank you

Comment: can you please share the code?

Answer (score 0):

class Window1(Window):
    def **init**(self):
        wpf.LoadComponent(self, r'....\myWindow.xaml')

```
def execute1(self)
    self.textBoxRes.Text += "\nExecuting step one -------------"
    text= internalCode()
    self.textBoxRes.Text += "\nEnd step 1 -------------"
    return text
def execute2(self)
    self.textBoxRes.Text += "\nExecuting step two-------------"
    text= internalCode2()
    self.textBoxRes.Text += "\nEnd step 2 -------------"
    return text
def execute3(self)
    self.textBoxRes.Text += "\nExecuting step three -------------"
    text= internalCode3()
    self.textBoxRes.Text += "\nEnd step 3 -------------"
    return text
def execute4(self)
    self.textBoxRes.Text += "\nExecuting step four-------------"
    text= internalCode4()
    self.textBoxRes.Text += "\End step 4. Result: "
    return text

def Execute_Click(self, sender, e):
    self.textBoxRes.Text = "Starting :"
    res1= self.execute1()
    if res1==0:
        res2=self.execute2()
        if res2==0:
            res3=self.execute3()
        if res3==0:
            res4= self.execute4()
    self.textBoxRes.Text += "Stop"
```

if **name** == '**main**':
    Application().Run(Window1())

Comment: Please,anyone could help me? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Lets assume you have a text box, to assign an entry to it just use .Text

Xaml:

```
<TextBox x:Name="ent" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="10,4,10,2"/>
```

IronPython code:

```
self.ent = self.FindName('ent')
self.ent.Text = ....
```

Answer (score 0):

Following snippet might help you.

XAML :

`<Label Content="" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="62,163,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="472" Width="880" Foreground="Black" FontSize="18" Background="White" x:Name="label1"/>`

IronPython :

`def Button_Click1(self, sender, e):
        self.label1 = self.FindName('label1')
        self.label1.Content = "Test Succeeded"
        pass`